# Fastest Way to (1) not insert duplicate entry (2) consolidate duplicates in Mongo DB?

Tags: python, mongodb

(1) What's the fastest way to check if an item I'm about to "insert" into a MongoDB collection is unique (and if so not insert it)

(2) For an existing database, what's the fastest way to look at all the entries and remove duplicates but keep one copy i.e. like a "set" function: {a,b,c,a,a,b} -> {a,b,c}

- I am aware that technically speaking each entry is unique, since they get a unique ObjectID
- You may assume the entries are completely flat key:value lists
- Solutions with indexing are fine
- I prefer Python code (i.e. mongo python API) if possible

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "unique"? Completely identical in every field other than `_id`?

Comment: @Adrian yes that's what I mean (and the flatness bit helps keep it simple:  {key:value, ..., key:value} )

Answer (score 2):

(1) Create a unique index on the related columns and catch the error upon insertion time

Comment: Could you explain a bit more on **how** I might do that? I'm very new to MongoDB unfortunately :/   By column do you mean a "key"? Also, "related" in which sense of the word?

Comment: Being "new" does not mean that you must not read the basic indexing documentation yourself. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes

Comment: You're absolutely right - after reading your answer that's exactly what I was reading right now =)